# Test passes but this warning appears: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: react-testing-library, ts-jest

I've built a simple react application with a searchbar component. The searchbar component contains an `<Input>`. For testing I'm using Jest with React Testing Library. I wrote the test below which passes but for some reason this warning appears:

`Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

It's referring `searchInput.value` in the code below. **How can I deal with this warning?**

Searchbar.test.tsx

```
test("SearchBar value is read", () => {
  const handleSearchRequest = jest.fn();
  render(<SearchBar searchInputValue="Hello World"/>);
  
  const searchInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Search");

  expect(searchInput.value).toBe("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `HTMLInputElement` (and/or `HTMLSelectElement` and `HTMLTextAreaElement`).

`getByPlaceholderText` is not very well named - as it's completely non-obvious what it returns. You should rename it to `getInputElementByPlaceholderText` and change its return-type to `HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement`.

As a quick-fix, use `as`:

```
test("SearchBar value is read", () => {
  const handleSearchRequest = jest.fn();
  render(<SearchBar searchInputValue="Hello World"/>);
  
  const searchInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Search") as HTMLInputElement | null;

  expect(searchInput?.value).toBe("Hello World");
});
```